# sql alchemy Update resultset of raw query

Tags: python-2.7, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Am new to Sql Alchemy. I have a raw sql which i need to execute by passing bind parameters. Resulting rows from the query, i need to update a particular column value. How do i do this in the efficient way?
Below are the columns in my table metrics

```
TABLE
id,total,pass,fail,category,ref_id

query = "Select * from table where id in(select max(id) from table ...)"
sql = text(query)
 result = db.engine.execute(sql, CATEGORY=category)
for row in result:
    //update here
```

So i have this complex query, that i need to execute as an inline query. Let's say i get three rows from my query and i need to update ref_id for all the 3 rows with a values. How can i achieve this preferably bulk update.
Am using python 2.7,SQLAlchemy==0.9.9,SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.29.8

Comment: Please provide more details as to what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you're after plain UPDATE statement.

Comment: I have updated the question. i need to execute some complex query and the resulting rows i have to update.